# Is the encryption of the password vault of MySql workbench secure enough?

Tags: mysql-workbench, encryption

MySql workbench stores passwords in a file called `user_data.dat` which is encrypted by default. But how strong is this encryption and what algorithm is used exactly? There are [tools available](https://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=41860.msg391762#msg391762) on the web that allow you to decrypt the `user_data.dat` file to recover a forgotten password. This made me wonder exactly how strong the encryption is and whether the password vault is safe enough to store the passwords of production databases in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not "tools available on the web" -- the page you link to clearly states that MySQL Workbench uses the CryptProtectData WIN32 API, which employs the [Triple-DES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms995355(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) algorithm and the key stored in the Windows user profile. This means that anyone who can log in as, or impersonate, the user that saved the credentials can also unencrypt those credentials. On the other hand, one who can do that also can simply launch the workbench and have at it.

Whether that is "safe enough" for your situation, only you can tell.